# Which beam deflects and twists more, open section or closed section?

Tags: beam, torque, deflection, bending

Two beams, one open section (like an I-beam with flanges and web) and the other closed section (like a hollow square section) are cantilevered and have the same overall cross sectional moment of inertia, material and length. Which beam will deflect more under concentrated load and twist more under concentrated torque, at the free end?

Comment: Sounds like if you punch the numbers you will then know.

Comment: Why wouldn't you actually answer the question instead of downvoting?

Comment: Sorry, I did not downvote, but I can easily correct that if you wish to accuse me.

Comment: This question sounds like homework.  I'm willing to _help_ you with your homework, but not just feed you an answer.  The purpose of homework is to _think through it all yourself_ so that, in practice, when presented with a similar problem, you can _think through it all yourself_.

Comment: @SolarMike, my bad. Pardon me for that.

Comment: @TimWescott, this is not a homework, actually. One of my collegues mentioned the other day that the closed section beams are usually more stiff than an open section one, which made me think what if the properties like cross sectional moment of Inertia, material, length, load, etc everything is the same for both, then what he said would still be correct or not, because I believe it won't make a difference since the factors that the deflection actually depends upon are the same for both.

Answer (score 2):

For a transverse force on the tip of the beam the deflection will be the same because M/I=E/R.

For a torque on the end of the beam about the long axis (call it the X axis) of the beam the I beam will have a lower torsional constant than the box section, so it will twist more.

For a torque at the end of the beam about the Y or Z axis the deflection will be the same because M/I=E/R.

Comment: Excuse me, @GregLocock in the last sentence, "the deflection will... "what?  I'll agree with the first sentence since in the problem statement, they have the same moment.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. Could you also specify any relation which proves that an I beam will have a lower one as compare to a box section? Plus, how is the torsional constant and twist related?

Comment: 1) only by googling, and you can google as well as I can. The approximate argument would go that for a given cross sectional area and maximum dimension a thin walled circular tube is optimum, and each deviation from that makes it worse. 2) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_constant